# get the last portion of the link using java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an `arraylist` links. All links having same format `abc.([a-z]*)/\\d{4}/`

```
List<String > links= new ArrayList<>();
        links.add("abc.com/2012/aa");
        links.add("abc.com/2014/dddd");
        links.add("abc.in/2012/aa");
```

I need to get the last portion of every link. ie, the part after domain name. Domain name can be anything(.com, .in, .edu etc).

```
/2012/aa
/2014/dddd
/2012/aa
```

This is the output i want. How can i get this using `regex`?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

(see [here](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) for background)

Why use regex ? Perhaps a simpler solution is to use `String.split("/")` , which gives you an array of substrings of the original string, split by `/`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) for more info.

Note that [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) does in fact take a regex to determine the boundaries upon which to split. However you don't need a regex in this case and a simple character specification is sufficient.

Comment: +1 for nice solution and quote... but is it true the [quote is incomplete](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-humor.html) (second par, two-problem quote)? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with below regex and use regex grouping feature that is grouped based on parenthesis ().

```
\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/.*)
```

*Pattern description* :

dot followed by two or three letters followed by forward slash then any characters

[DEMO](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xAs2yZGyzI0j45sA)

Sample code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abc.com/2012/aa");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
/2012/aa
```

**Note:**

You can make it more precise by using `\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\d{4}/.*)` if there are always 4 digits in the pattern.

Comment: what if the pattern is abc.edu?

Comment: it mean he has to add all kind of url patterns in the list

Answer (score 1):

- Use [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop to iterate over list.
- Use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and [indexOf('/')](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29).

**FOR EXAMPLE**

```
String s="abc.com/2014/dddd";
System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf('/')));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/2014/dddd
```

---

Or you can go for `split` method.

```
System.out.println(s.split("/",2)[1]);//OUTPUT:2014/dddd --->you need to add /
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String result = s.replaceAll("^[^/]*","");
```

`s` would be the string in your list.

Answer (score 1):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.” Now they have two problems.

Why not just use the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class?

```
output = new URI(link).getPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one and use the second capturing group

`(.*?)(/.*)`